# Ionic 4: Video Upload Error with Media Capture Plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I’m developing an application using Ionic with Angular Framework. In my application, I need to capture a video and upload it to a server. For that, I’m using [media-capture plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media-capture) for capturing video and [file transfer plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer) for uploading it to server.

Here is the code that I’m using it for capturing and uploading it to a remote server:

```html
// Capturing Video 
captureVideo() {
    let options: CaptureVideoOptions = { limit: 1 }
    this.mediaCapture.captureVideo(options)
      .then((videoData: MediaFile[]) => {
        var i, path, len;
        for (i = 0, len = videoData.length; i < len; i += 1) {
          path = videoData[i].fullPath;
        }
        this.videoPath = path;
        console.log(this.videoPath);
      })
      .catch((err: CaptureError) => err)
  }

// Uploading Video
uploadVideo() {

    var options: FileUploadOptions = {
      fileKey: "videos",
      fileName: 'sample.mp4',
      chunkedMode: false,
      mimeType: "video/mp4"
    }

    var params: any = {};
    params.typeOfItemGroup = "SPACE";
    params.itemGroupName = "Kitchen";
    options.params = params;

    console.log("options: ", options);

    this.videoFileUpload = this.fileTransfer.create();

    this.videoFileUpload.upload(this.videoPath, 'localhost:8081/api/v1/shield/camera/video/5e706f96b5587e5e6776614f', options)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("Data: " + data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error in upload: ", err);
      });
  }
```

The Error I’m getting is:[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3tB2.png)

I’m not able to figure it out the code: 2 error.

For Backend It’s working fine as below:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbk2s.png)

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Karumuri

Answer (score 0):

File transfer plugin is deprecated. I suggest you have a look at this article for alternatives to upload the file:
https://cordova.apache.org/blog/2017/10/18/from-filetransfer-to-xhr2.html.

Error code 2 refers to invalid url. You can find the error codes in the docs:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/README.md#constants

Answer (score -1):

### use `Capacitor.convertFileSrc(*your mediacpture result.fullPath*);`

> Then you get webPath ◄ this is what we are looking for
> Then Utilize that for making blob or displaying it in UI or Uploading blob to server...

I hope it helps works 100% 4 me.